# Что не подлежит юнит-тестированию?

Tags: java, юнит-тесты

1. Нужно ли тестировать методы-делегаты? Есть класс Task, в котором
   есть вот такой метод:

   ```
   public void setValue(int value, int row, int col) {
       if (col == variableCount + 1) {
           limits.set(row - criterionCount, value);
           return;
       }
       if (row < criterionCount) {
           costs.get(row).set(col, value);
           return;
       }
       if (row >= criterionCount) {
           weights.get(row - criterionCount).set(col, value);
       }
   }
   ```

   В классе Task этот метод протестирован.

   Есть другой класс в котором есть такой метод:

   ```
   setText(int value, int row, int col){
       task.setText(value, row, col);
   }
   ```

   Нужно ли его тестировать?
2. Как протестировать анонимный класс?

   ```
    ((AbstractDocument) field.getDocument())
                       .setDocumentFilter(new DocumentFilter() {
                           @Override
                           public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int off,
                                   String str, AttributeSet attr)
                                   throws BadLocationException {
                               fb.insertString(off, str.replaceAll("\\D++", ""), attr); // remove
                                                                                       // non-digits
                       }

                       @Override
                       public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int off, int len,
                               String str, AttributeSet attr)
                               throws BadLocationException {
                           fb.replace(off, len, str.replaceAll("\\D++", ""), attr); // remove
                                                                                       // non-digits
                       }
                   });
   ```

   Нужно обязательно создавать неанонимный класс, тестировать его и потом создавать его объекты?

   3.Как тестировать паттерн состояние? Интересует тот метод, который тестирует геттер объекта состояние. Вот он:

   ```
   @Override
   public TableManager getTableManager() {
       return tableManager;
   }
   ```

   Класс `tableManager` устанавливается в зависимости от условия. Покажу упрощенный код.

   ```
   if(isFirstState()){
       tableManager = new FirstState();
   }
   else{
       tableManager = new SecondState();
   }
   ```

   Как это протестировать? Получается что в тестах придется использовать `instanceof`.

Answer (score 2):

1. В идеале нужно. Но на практике обычно избегают тестирования подобного
   тривиального кода (типа геттеров/сеттеров и вот таких
   прокси-методов).
2. Создать неанонимный класс и протестировать его. Иначе тесты чересчур
   усложнятся: вам надо будет создать множество объектов и правильно
   настроить их для того чтобы протестировать код, который лежит где-то
   "в глубине". Да еще и не факт, что можно будет легко сделать
   проверку.
3. Да, проверяйте тип возвращаемого объекта, это нормально. Иногда тест установки `tableManager` можно и опустить, если этот код тривиален, а класс верхнего уровня покрыт хорошими тестами, которые упадут при неправильном типе `tableManager`.